# Clipping raster by value of overlapping raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I have two overlapping raster dataset with the same resolution. First one is classified into 1 and 0 values. I would like to clip the second raster based on the pixels of the fist raster with value equal to 1.

Is there any tool that can do this job in QGIS?

Comment: Try **Clip Raster by Mask Layer** from menu `Raster > Extraction`.

Comment: @Kazuhito The extraction tool requires a vector layer, so the first step will be to convert the raster to vector and then use appropriate vector  features for the clipping.

Answer (score 3):

You can clip a raster by a vector easily, so first step is to convert your raster to vector.

1. GDAL > Raster Conversion > Polygonize.
2. You will have polygons with attribute called DN with values 0 and 1. Select all polygons with value 1 with expression like `DN = 1`
3. Use GDAL > Raster Extraction > Clip raster by mask layer. Select the polygonized layer as the mask layer and check the 'selected features only'

Comment: Thank you @spatialthoughts. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use raster calculator for this:

1. Select 'Raster' > 'Raster Calculator...' use the expression `("Mask_raster@1"=1)*"Raster1@1" + ("Mask_raster@1"=0)*-9999` (replace Mask_raster and Raster1 with your layer names).
2. Select 'Raster' > 'Conversion' > 'Translate (Convert Format)...'. Set the input layer as the layer you just created in raster calculator and assign the nodata value as `-9999`.